# Initialize object via setter in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, setter

Is there a better way to call an external setter during initialization other than doing it in the body of a constructor?

Example:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo()
        : object(someValue)
        // can't do this:
        // , object.setProperty(differentValue)
    {
        // have to call it here
        object.setProperty(differentValue);
    }
}
```

Assuming the `object` class is external and can't be modified to prevent having to use a setter.

Comment: Some mini-factory function that creates the object you want and returns it, then use that in the initialiser list? Though consider the costs of any extra copying/moving.

Comment: why don't you want to use a setter?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: Nah, that's as good as it gets if you can't fix the type in question. Anything else risks undue complexity.

Comment: you can also inherit from object, add any constructor you like, there should be no difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way, but I wouldn't say it's better.

You can have another struct in your code:

```
struct Helper {
    Helper(Object &object, int differentValue) {
        object.setProperty(differentValue);
    }
}
```

And in `Foo`

```
struct Foo {
    Object object;
    Helper helper; // after object

    Foo() : object(someValue), helper(object, differentValue) {
    }
}
```

But it's just a trick, and it's not better by any means.

You could also have `Foo` inherit from `Helper`, instead of `helper` being a member of `Foo`.

Comment: Don't inherit just for the sake of code reuse. "Favour composition over inheritance."

Comment: @CraigYoung - Judge each case by itself, and don't be dogmatic. Composition here is a pessimization. It increases object size needlessly, while any compiler worth its salt will do the empty base optimization.

Comment: @coyotte - It's worth mentioning the inheritance better be private in this case. `Foo` is not a `Helper`, only implemented in terms of one.

Comment: No wait.. actually inheritance won't work here. The base will always be initialized first, leading to UB.

Comment: @StoryTeller I agree "don't be dogmatic". (_It's just typically too much typing for the detailed explanation._) Inheritance is a stronger dependency than composition. When used inappropriately it leads to a breakdown in design. Typically not an issue in trivial examples; and perhaps less so in C++; because its support for multiple inheritance should mitigate against the tendency towards bloated "base-classes" that are so prevalent in other languages. That said it is semantically peculiar to treat an object as something entirely different because of what it can do instead of what it ***is***.

Comment: @StoryTeller it could work if object was in `Helper`, and then `Foo`'s constructor would be `Foo(): Helper(somevalue, differentValue)`. It's just a theoretical solution, not something I advise :)